# Javascript - Round 1,675 to 1,67 - By default it rounds to 1,68

Tags: javascript, jquery, rounding

Any idea how to round `1.675` to `1.67`?

By default it rounds to `1.68`:

```js
Math.round(1.675 * 100) / 100; // 1.68
```

By the way if the number is `1.676`, it should still rounds to `1.68`, as expected.

Comment: Math.floor(1.675 * 100) / 100

Comment: thanks @ASDFGerte, it worked.. you`re fast!!

Comment: This type of information is part of language learning. I hope you will not prefer to post a question every time you get lazy to look in the language documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript

Comment: @ASDFGerte Using `floor` would break results for `1.676`.

Comment: @MisterJojo Check my answer and you'll see that was not that simple ;)

Comment: @zessx i didn't understand the question that way, before the edit. That's different then, of course.

Answer (score 0):

We need to go deeper that it appeared first…

[ECMA-262](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%201st%20edition,%20June%201997.pdf) defines `Math.round()` like this:

> Returns the number value that is closest to the argument and is equal to a mathematical integer. **If two integer number values are equally close to the argument, then the result is the number value that is closer to +∞.** If the argument is already an integer, the result is the argument itself.

The bold part is important as you'll get these results:

```js
Math.round(1.674 * 100) / 100;  //  1.67
Math.round(1.675 * 100) / 100;  //  1.68 (wrong)
Math.round(1.676 * 100) / 100;  //  1.68

Math.round(-1.674 * 100) / 100; // -1.67
Math.round(-1.675 * 100) / 100; // -1.67
Math.round(-1.676 * 100) / 100; // -1.68
```

See how it already works as you're expecting for negative numbers!

If you want to reverse the `1.675` rounded value, you cannot use `Math.floor()` as this will change all you other results:

```js
Math.floor(1.674 * 100) / 100;  //  1.67
Math.floor(1.675 * 100) / 100;  //  1.67
Math.floor(1.676 * 100) / 100;  //  1.67 (wrong)

Math.floor(-1.674 * 100) / 100; // -1.68 (wrong)
Math.floor(-1.675 * 100) / 100; // -1.68 (wrong)
Math.floor(-1.676 * 100) / 100; // -1.68
```

---

My solution would be to use this Javascript specificity that it search **the closest value to +∞**.

1. Take your number `1.675`
2. Get its absolute value `1.675` (this is for negative numbers)
3. Negate it `-1.675`
4. Use `round()` to get the closest value to +∞ `-1.67`
5. Negate it back if it was a positive number initially `1.67`

Proof of concept:

```js
function _round(value, precision) {
  var shift = Math.pow(10, precision);
  var negateBack = Math.abs(value) / -value;
  return Math.round(Math.abs(value) * -1 * shift) / shift * negateBack;
}

_round(1.674, 2);  //  1.67
_round(1.675, 2);  //  1.67
_round(1.676, 2);  //  1.68

_round(-1.674, 2); // -1.67
_round(-1.675, 2); // -1.67
_round(-1.676, 2); // -1.68
```

Comment: `_round(2.365, 2)` gives `2.37` for me. Is that the expected result?

Comment: It is not the expected result, but this makes me feel depressed: `console.log(-2.365 * 100); // 236.50000000000003`